# quick formatting shortcut sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2

I was wondering if someone had the sequence of steps to accomplish this task, inline, without copy and pasting.

Imagine you have a block of code where things are not cleanly justified

```
{
    foo: "foo value",
    bar: "bar value",
    reallylongvariable:     "reallylongvariable value",
    shortname:     "shortname value"
}
```

is there a very quick way to transform it in this, justifying the spaces and ragged spacing to a unified formatting

```
{
    foo:                "foo value",
    bar:                "bar value",
    reallylongvariable: "reallylongvariable value",
    shortname:          "shortname value"
}
```

I know about option selection. Generally, I follow these steps

- option select a column,
- paste it on a new set of lines,
- reselect pasted content
- use **command + [** to remove indention,
- option reselect column of unindented content
- past back in place in the original column.

But this process feels very manual, and was wonder if there was way to clean up the indentation inline, without copy and paste. Perhaps a helper utility that can do this automatically within a highlighted selection.

Hopefully my question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple plugins for this task, for example:

https://github.com/wbond/sublime_alignment

https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab

Here you can search for all of them: https://sublime.wbond.net/search/align

I personally recommend the [AlignTab](https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab). It may seem complex, but if you know how to use regular expressions it is the most powerful you will find. It may do some crazy magic if you get used to it.